# Split <endpoint1>,<endpoint2> efficiently with Regex/Split() (?)

Tags: java, regex, split

> I am currently working on a user interface and have already implemented the command `add track <startpoint> -> <endpoint>`.
>
> Now, I want to implement the command `add switch <startpoint> -> <endpoint1>,<endpoint2>`.
>
> However, I am not sure how to efficiently split the third argument (`<endpoint1>,<endpoint2>`).
>
> This is how I've done it with the `add track` command:

```
        String startPointStr = InputPattern.parsePoint(args.get(0));
        String endPointStr = InputPattern.parsePoint(args.get(2));

        // TODO: Can I improve the code?
        String[] startCoords = startPointStr.substring(1, startPointStr.length() - 1).split(",");
        Point startPoint = new Point(Integer.parseInt(startCoords[0]), Integer.parseInt(startCoords[1]));

        String[] endCoords = endPointStr.substring(1, endPointStr.length() - 1).split(",");
        Point endPoint = new Point(Integer.parseInt(endCoords[0]), Integer.parseInt(endCoords[1]));
```

*Btw: Point = `(<x-coordinate>,<y-coordinate>)`. The method parsePoint checks the pattern for "\(\d+,\d+\)" with Regex.*

So I want to create another Point `Point secondEndPoint = new Point(...);` for endpoint2. How could I do this (regex, .split(), ..., ?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do everything with `split` as you are doing it. But if you want to be more flexible as to what you allow as input, you might allow the user to to use or *not* use spaces more freely. For example, a user might be allowed to enter a coordinate as `(123, 456)`. Or it may not be necessary to have spaces on either side of the `->` operator. In that case, one regex could be used to recognize the complete command:

```
^\s*add\s+switch\s*(?:\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\))\s*->\s*(?:\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\))\s*,\s*(?:\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\))\s*$
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/kpCzDQ/3/)

1. `^\s*add\s+switch\s*` Matches the start of the string followed by 0 or more spaces followed by `add` followed by 1 or more spaces followed by `switch` followed 0 or more spaces.
2. `(?:\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\))` A coordinate: A `(` followed by 0 or more spaces followed by 1 or more digits followed by 0 or more spaces followed by a `,` followed by 0 or more spaces followed by 1 or more digits followed by 0 or more spaces followed by a `)`.
3. `\s*->\s*` Matches 0 or more spaces followed by `->` followed by 0 or more spaces.
4. `(?:\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\))` Matches a coordinate.
5. `\s*,\s*` Matches 0 or more spaces followed by `,` followed by 0 or more spaces.
6. `(?:\(\s*(\d+)\s*,\s*(\d+)\s*\))` Matches a coordinate.
7. `\s*$` Matches 0 or more spaces followed by the end of string.

The first coordinate will be in capture groups 1 and 2, the second coordinate in capture groups 3 and 4 and the third coordinate in capture groups 5 and 6.

Sample Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String tests[] = {
            "add switch(123,456)->(45,67),(8,100)",
            "  add switch (19 , 310) -> (21 , 890) , (1 ,  2)  "
        };
        for (String test: tests) {
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\s*add\\s+switch\\s*(?:\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\))\\s*->\\s*(?:\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\))\\s*,\\s*(?:\\(\\s*(\\d+)\\s*,\\s*(\\d+)\\s*\\))\\s*$");
            Matcher m = pattern.matcher(test);
            if (m.find()) {
                for (int i = 0; i <= 6; ++i) {
                    System.out.println("Group " + i + " = " + m.group(i));
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Prints:

```
Group 0 = add switch(123,456)->(45,67),(8,100)
Group 1 = 123
Group 2 = 456
Group 3 = 45
Group 4 = 67
Group 5 = 8
Group 6 = 100

Group 0 =   add switch (19 , 310) -> (21 , 890) , (1 ,  2)
Group 1 = 19
Group 2 = 310
Group 3 = 21
Group 4 = 890
Group 5 = 1
Group 6 = 2
```